# Is there a term to refer to the back view of a person?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know "profile" refers to a side view of a person's face, but is there any common terms that means the image of a person seen from behind?

rear profile?

back figure?

hind view?

[image: Full height picture of a person from behind]

Answer (score 1):

In art, **back view** and **rear view** are both widely used for images of this sort.

Bridgeman art library uses "rear view" as a tag ([search](https://www.bridgemanimages.co.uk/en/search?filter_text=%22rear%20view%22&filter_group=all&filter_region=GBR&sort=most_popular)) while the National Portrait Gallery in London seems to prefer "back view" ([search](https://www.npg.org.uk/collections/search/portrait-list.php?search=sp&sText=back%20view&firstRun=true&OConly=true)); the Smithsonian uses both but more "back view" ([search](https://americanart.si.edu/search?query=back+view)).

(Sorry this isn't a single word answer, but it's not clear if one is required because the tag seems to contradict the question.)